# stop the indicator after file loads

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to display a file on tap of button. But before the file loads, I want the circular progress indicator to start and after the file loads, I want it to stop. I have implemented the following code but the problem is the indicator keeps on loading even after file loads.

```
  InkWell(

    onTap: () async {
      player.stop();



         Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );

      final files = await loadPdfFromNetwork(file.url);
      openPdf(context, files, file.url,file.name.split('.').first);



    }
```

Comment: not sure why you have a widget inside your function. pls show the complete code for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Navigator.of(context).pop .

InkWell(

```
onTap: () async {
  player.stop();



     Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );

  final files = await loadPdfFromNetwork(file.url);
  openPdf(context, files, file.url,file.name.split('.').first);
```

Navigator.of(context).pop

```
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream builder to avoid any error in future as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).